# Is there any way to define a dictionary outside of a function in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am creating a 3D orbital mechanics simulator with Unity and C# and want to use dictionaries to store planet data for physics calculations. However, the only way I've found so far of declaring and populating a dictionary in C# requires that it lie within a function, which prevents it from being referenced by other functions.

The dictionary is created in `void Start()` as follows:

```
var earth = new Dictionary<string,double>(){
    {"mass", 5.972e24}, // kg
    {"mu", 5.972e24 * G},
    {"radius", 6051.8}, // km
    {"sma", 108.209e6}, // km
    {"SOI", 617183.2511}, // km
    {"deorbit_altitude", 100.0} // km
};
```

When I later reference a value from the dictionary in another function:

```
void two_body_ode(double time, double state)
{
    return -state * (float)earth["mu"] / Mathf.Pow(r.normalized.x, 3);
}
```

I am told that "The name 'earth' does not exist in the current context". Is there another way to declare a static dictionary so that it may be referenced by other functions within a class?

Comment: As a C# programmer, I'm certain you can define class-scoped variables - including dictionaries - in C# classes. Have you tried that? If that didn't work, what went wrong? If you want the dictionary to be static, just put the `static` keyword in front while defining it (e.g. `static Dictionary<string, double> earth = new()`).

Comment: When I say class-scoped, I mean that you should define and populate the dictionary inside of the class, but not one of the methods.

Comment: In C#, scope is important. Things can be at the class level as `static` (which means there is on instance of the class, shared amount any class instance), at the class level as an instance member (inherent is s different object for each instance of the class) or at the method (or property level) - these go out of scope when the execution of the method ends (more or less)

Comment: @AbeMonk I tried your suggestion and it worked. I had tried using `static` before but my syntax was incorrect. Thank you!

Comment: If you are going to use a static dictionary and it isn't going to be _immutable_ (unchanging) you need to be careful to access it from only a single thread at a time

Comment: **declaring** a variable or object is different from **initializing** them.  Learn and Profit!

Comment: @Liam Dwyer I've looked at **derHugo's** answer, and some of what he said I think could be useful to you. Dictionaries are really meant to store dynamic data - data that changes. Your planet values don't seem to change. Therefore, you'd be better off creating `static` classes for all your planets, and then initializing `const` fields inside of them, seeing as they are compile-time constants that won't change.

Comment: @Liam Dwyer Using interfaces (e.g. a `Planet` interface) that your static planet classes inherit from, you could make this even better and less error prone

Comment: Using generic methods that take in one of the planet classes derived from the interface, you could even create methods that would dynamically work on *any* planet (e.g. `void two_body_ode<TPlanet>(...params...) where TPlanet : IPlanet`). You would call, for example, like `two_body_ode<Earth>(...args...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of ["scopes"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp).

In `c#` each code block, method or type (basically anything wrapped between `{ }` + some other cases) is it's own scope.

In your case

```
private void Start()
{ // begin of scope

    var earth = new Dictionary<string,double>()
    {
        {"mass", 5.972e24}, // kg
        {"mu", 5.972e24 * G},
        {"radius", 6051.8}, // km
        {"sma", 108.209e6}, // km
        {"SOI", 617183.2511}, // km
        {"deorbit_altitude", 100.0} // km
    };

    ...
} // <- END of scope of the Start method! => As earth is declared within this scope it is not known outside of it
```

> Is there any way to define a dictionary outside of a function in C#

Of course, you can have fields on type (class / struct) level scope in `c#` (and any other OOP language)!

There are of course thousands of ways to do and solve this.

The most trivial would be to simply move it outside of the method into the class scope and do

```
private Dictionary<string,double> earth; // declared on class level scope -> known to entire class content

private void Start()
{
    // initialized in Start -> before this it will be null
    earth = new Dictionary<string,double>
    {
        {"mass", 5.972e24}, // kg
        {"mu", 5.972e24 * G},
        {"radius", 6051.8}, // km
        {"sma", 108.209e6}, // km
        {"SOI", 617183.2511}, // km
        {"deorbit_altitude", 100.0} // km
    };
}
```

now the dictionary is known to the entire class scope and initialized by start and available until the class instance "dies".

However, in your case those seem to be even never intended to change at all so you could already initialize it **once** and further even share the same instance between all instances of this class - there is no need that every instance hosts one individually -> make it [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) and optimally also [`readonly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) which the compiler can optimize even more

```
// declared static => not bound to an instance of this class but to the type itself
// => exists exactly ONCE and is "shared" among all instaces
// declared readonly => Can only be accessed but never re-assigned
// directly initialized
private static readonly IReadOnlyDictonary<string, double> earth = new Dictionary<string, double>
{
    {"mass", 5.972e24}, // kg
    {"mu", 5.972e24 * G},
    {"radius", 6051.8}, // km
    {"sma", 108.209e6}, // km
    {"SOI", 617183.2511}, // km
    {"deorbit_altitude", 100.0} // km
}
```

**But** why even go by `string` at all - this is error prone and slow. You could rather have an `enum` and do e.g.

```
// basically a list of int (byte in this case) with sequential values with proper names
public enum EarthProperty : byte //or maybe even generic PlanetProperty ?
{
    Mass_Kg,   // implicit = 0
    Mu,        // implicit = 1
    Radius_Km, // etc
    Sma_Km,
    SOI_Km,
    DeorbitAltidude_Km
}

private static readonly IReadOnlyDictonary<string, double> earth = new Dictionary<EarthProperty, double>
{
    {EarthProperty.Mass_Kg, 5.972e24}, 
    {EarthProperty.Mu, 5.972e24 * G},
    {EarthProperty.Radius_Km, 6051.8}, 
    {EarthProperty.Sma_Km, 108.209e6}, 
    {EarthProperty.SOI_Km, 617183.2511},
    {EarthProperty.DeorbitAltidude_Km, 100.0} 
}
```

would access these via e.g.

```
(float)earth[EarthProperty.Mu]
```

If you will have multiple different sets of those for different planets it would make sense to instead of using various dictionaries even have a class/struct and do e.g.

```
// Again there a tons of ways for how to implement this
// This is just an example that defaults to earth values and can be configured via the Inspector
[Serializable]
public class Planet
{
    public string Name = "Earth";
    public double Mass_Kg = 5.972e24;
    public double Mu = 5.972e24 * G;
    public double Radius_Km = 6051.8;
    public double Sma_Km = 108.209e6;
    public double SOI_Km = 617183.2511;
    public double DeorbitAltidude_Km = 100.0;
}

private static readonly Planet earth = new Planet();
private static readonly Planet planetOfTheApes = new Planet
{
    Name = "Soror",
    Mess_Kg = ...
    ...
};
```

**But** even further none of these seem to ever change at all. So - unless you really need to group those and e.g. have multiple sets of those constants for different planets - actually it would be even better to simply use actual constants and do

```
const double Earth_Mass_Kg = 5.972e24;
const double Earth_Mu = 5.972e24 * G;
const double Earth_Radius_Km = 6051.8;
const double Earth_Sma_Km = 108.209e6;
const double Earth_SOI_Km = 617183.2511;
const double Earth_DeorbitAltidude_Km =  100.0;
```